# How to progressively hide the BottomNavigationBar component when the SlidingUpPanel component goes down?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, bottom-navigation-bar

Hope everyone is fine.

I would like to hide the BottomNavigationBar when the component SlidingUpPanel is going down.

```
https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel
```

Like the same behavior of the Airbnb application (2023)

For people who have experimented the subject, I used the "onPanelSlide" property by calculating the position of the SlideUpPanel component but there are lags...
It's not convenient and professionnal

Do you have any ideas..?

Thank you in advance of your help.

Mika

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a dialog instead of a panel inside your widget. The dialog will simply overlap the bottomNavigationBar and the problems will be gone. I am currently using the showSlidingBottomSheet method from https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel2 to show a sheetDialog.

In addition, I don't foresee any problems using onPanelSlide to manage the navigationBar height. Remember that Flutter animations do not work well when debugging. I suggest you try the animation in profile or release environments.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for taking the time to answer me.

But unfortunately that's not exactly what I want to do.
I don't want the "BottomNavigationBar" component to be visible when the panel is in the bottom position.
Like on Airbnb application, the bottom bar will gradually disappear.

I have a nice first version of my MVP,I think I'm complicating my life with little details.

Thanks again

Comment: Ok, no problem. I think I could help you with that. I am also finishing my MVP and this component maddened me.

Comment: Ahaha.
I can imagine ;)